# Connection String en asp net core

Tags: asp.net-core

estoy probando de conectarme a la base de datos en asp net core y no estoy pudiendo.
Mi consulta es como se escribe la cadena de conexion cuando se utiliza windows authentication?
Yo lo tengo asi.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConexionSQL": "server=DESKTOP-NENB34B\\SQLEXPRESS;database=Usuarios;Trusted_Connection=true"
  }
```

Y al momento de hacer la migracion me sale este error

```
  A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. 
  The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL 
  Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error 
  Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

Comment: tenes  el sistema y la base en la misma computadora? Tenes corriendo el motor de sql?

Comment: Hola, que tal?. Si y si.

Answer (score 1):

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConexionSQL": "server=localhost;database=Usuarios;Trusted_Connection=true"
  }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me funciono!!

Comment: Coloca como valida la respuesta.